# How to trigger callbacks on associated model when no changes with ActiveAdmin association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin with Rails 5. I have the following associations in place.

```
class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manager

  after_save :do_something
end
```

And my form looks like this:

```
tabs do 
  tab 'Details' do 
    f.inputs do
      input :name
      input :current_address
      input :email_address
    end 
  end

  tab 'Employees' do 
    f.has_many :employees, heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |employee|
      input :name
      input :experience
      input :email_address
    end
  end
end
```

On the manager edit page, if I only edit the manager details not the employee details, the after_save callback on the employee model is not triggered, which makes sense. But is there a way I can force to trigger the callback on employee model even though employee details are not changed?

Answer (score 0):

How about having an after_save method in Manager model that will trigger callbacks in Employee model?

```
class Manager < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :employees
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees, :allow_destroy => true

  after_save :update_employees

  def update_employees
    employees.each {|m| m.update_attributes()}
  end

end
```

Comment: It solves the problem. But on the manager edit page if I edit employee along with manager details after_save on the employee model called twice. The way active admin works is it first saves the associated records and then the parent record. Any other ideas?